# Move files from Mac OSX to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, macos

I am trying to move my `sickbeard.db` file from my Mac running OS X 10.9 to my Raspberry Pi so that Sickbeard can run on the Pi and not my Mac.

I am unable to tell what the username and password to the Sickbeard directory is. I can log in using Cyberduck and am ready to upload my `.ini` and `db` files, but it says I don't have sufficient permission with the standard username password that the Raspberry Pi was set up with.

Looking at the [supplied code](http://techtutes.net/post/55067052101/media-services-on-rpi#.Uqp98JHDOf3) (and since I am not a programmer), I can't tell which line is the username and which is the password.

---

Create sickbeard user

```
$ sudo useradd --system --user-group --no-create-home sickbeard
```

Download, extract, move to correct location and set permissions

```
$ git clone git://github.com/midgetspy/Sic...
$ sudo mv Sick-Beard /usr/local/sickbeard
$ sudo chown -R sickbeard:nzb /usr/local/sickbeard
$ sudo chmod ug+rw /usr/local/sickbeard/autoProcessTV/
$ sudo mkdir /var/sickbeard
$ sudo chown sickbeard:nzb /var/sickbeard
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the above code snippet isn't setting the password for the sickbeard user.
You could just do it manually with the command below?

```
sudo passwd sickbeard
```

Comment: This worked!  Once I assigned a password to the user, I was able to then make changes.  Thanks so much Alastair!!!  :-)